# Relation between bosonization and conformal field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, conformal-field-theory, bosonization

Recently I have been studying bosonization for 1-dimensional system. There are often some claims of bosonization being related to conformal field theory. I know that one could map 1+1D quantum field into a 2D classical field, but is there any more direct connection or more intuitive explanation on those two? Some references would be preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see these claims? There is a very loose connection between the two at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bosonization means you map some problems (i.e. interacting fermions) to free (compact) scalar field theory, which is perhaps the simplest example of 1+1 CFT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I understand correctly, the Hamiltonian after the mapping (a quadratic bosonic Hamiltonian) is conformal invariant (which could be treated in CFT). I was wondering if the mapping from a fermionic model to a bosonic one (fermionic operator to density fluctuations) would be a conformal transformation (undercover).

Comment: To be clear, the Hamiltonian after the mapping is usually not conformally invariant. A free Dirac fermion and a free scalar are both CFTs and they are related by bosonization. But the paradigm case in bosonization is between the massive Thirring model and the Sine-Gordon model, neither of which are CFTs.

Comment: So bosonization itself is not necessarily related to CFT, but the model before and after mappying could be CFTs, right?